# Ubuntu 20.04 shuts down suddenly

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, cpu

My Ubuntu 20.04 shuts down suddenly, without particular stress on the machine (just while surfing the internet).

From `cat /var/log/kern.log | grep 'Error'` around the last shutdown time:

```
May 23 10:07:18 hal9000 kernel: [  628.089083] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
May 23 10:07:18 hal9000 kernel: [  628.089086] [Hardware Error]: Corrected error, no action required.
May 23 10:07:18 hal9000 kernel: [  628.089090] [Hardware Error]: CPU:0 (17:71:0) MC25_STATUS[-|CE|MiscV|-|-|-|-|CECC|-|-|-]: 0x98004000003e0000
May 23 10:07:18 hal9000 kernel: [  628.089094] [Hardware Error]: IPID: 0x000100ff03830400
May 23 10:07:18 hal9000 kernel: [  628.089096] [Hardware Error]: Platform Security Processor Ext. Error Code: 62
May 23 10:07:18 hal9000 kernel: [  628.089097] [Hardware Error]: cache level: RESV, tx: INSN
May 23 10:08:55 hal9000 kernel: [    0.535518] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
May 23 10:19:17 hal9000 kernel: [  627.703179] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
May 23 10:19:17 hal9000 kernel: [  627.703182] [Hardware Error]: Corrected error, no action required.
May 23 10:19:17 hal9000 kernel: [  627.703187] [Hardware Error]: CPU:0 (17:71:0) MC25_STATUS[-|CE|MiscV|-|-|-|-|CECC|-|-|-]: 0x98004000003e0000
May 23 10:19:17 hal9000 kernel: [  627.703191] [Hardware Error]: IPID: 0x000100ff03830400
May 23 10:19:17 hal9000 kernel: [  627.703193] [Hardware Error]: Platform Security Processor Ext. Error Code: 62
May 23 10:19:17 hal9000 kernel: [  627.703195] [Hardware Error]: cache level: RESV, tx: INSN
```

My `lscpu`

```
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   43 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          16
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-15
Thread(s) per core:              2
Core(s) per socket:              8
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       AuthenticAMD
CPU family:                      23
Model:                           113
Model name:                      AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8-Core Processor
Stepping:                        0
Frequency boost:                 enabled
CPU MHz:                         3349.889
CPU max MHz:                     5224,2178
CPU min MHz:                     2200,0000
BogoMIPS:                        7187.05
Virtualization:                  AMD-V
L1d cache:                       256 KiB
L1i cache:                       256 KiB
L2 cache:                        4 MiB
L3 cache:                        32 MiB
```

I am on NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 INNO3D.

Any Clue?

Comment: Could be this bug. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1903915

Comment: Is that machine overclocked?

Comment: Similar problem: https://forums.unraid.net/topic/96184-machine-check-events-detected-on-your-server/

Comment: @HuHa no it’s not.

Comment: It _could_ be this: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=212399

Comment: @nobody thanks! I will check it out ASAP

Comment: @HuHa oook I am going to test if some of this option can work. I also updated the kernel today but it got rebooted again after it so its not that probably...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the suggestions in comments, I came to the conclusion to reset my BIOS to default settings. It turned out that so far so good, no sudden reboots in the last 12 hours.

Probably was that.

Comment: Nicely done. Any idea what settings might have been changed?

Comment: @Zanna so I am not sure but I guess was something related to my RAM settings. I cannot tell precisely.